# Why Does My Ancient Magic Bar Deplete Upon Save and Exit?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I have upgraded my Ancient Magic bar to 4. It builds up normally through combat. But all full 4 bars deplete to 2 bars upon saving and exiting the game. I would like to save all 4 full bars for tough boss fights. I have looked in perks/talents but found nothing there to prevent this.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Comment: I have strong feeling that this is a bug. Was it happening when your bar was 3 or below?

Comment: @Skye-AT At 3 it was less noticeable. I went back to a previous save and it does that at 3 bars also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no, there is nothing you can do to prevent this.

Not sure if it's a feature, because you originally start out at 2 bars so it just takes you down to the original amount or if it's a bug where the game doesn't account for the upgrades.

There is no perk or equipment you can equip that allows you to modify this stat in any way either.